# Why is the variable value not updating from null to the latest value in the given scenario?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am working on a project where I want to upload files to firebase storage and add that url to the firestore. I am able to print the updated value of the variable `urlDownload` to the console but unable to send the same to firestore, instead the corresponding field in firestore is showing null value. I know I am basically doing something wrong, please help me in figuring it out.

Here is the the link to code. Mainly observe variable `urlDownload` mentioned in lines 11,94,128.
https://pastebin.com/8HWXgS9b

```
.
.
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  UploadTask? task;
  File? file;
  String? urlDownload;

  List<String> types = [
.
.
  onPressed: () async {
                await uploadFile();
                await addFile(
                  _namecontroller.text,
                  dropdownValue,
                  urlDownload,
                );
              },
.
.
 Future uploadFile() async {
    .
    .
    final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    setState(() {});

    print('Download-Link: $urlDownload');
  }
```

Comment: None of the code in your question is doing anything with Firestore, so it's impossible to say what is going wrong. Please make sure that all code that is needed to reproduce the problem is in the question itself, while still keeping it minimal. For hints on how to do this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled the global variable (`urlDownlaod` vs `urlDownload`). You are also assigning the download url to a local variable in the uploadFile function. Try correcting the name and removing the `final` keyword on line 128.

Just a tip: You can return the download url from uploadFile instead of making it a class wide variable since you are not using it anywhere else. It reduces the complexity a little bit in my opinion.

Comment: I fixed the spelling and removed final keyword, now it is working. Lol I spent around an hour on this. Thank you.